# Create Google Maps links based on coordinates - bug pin position

Tags: google-maps

i tried make link to Google maps and place pin in position based on coordinates.
Make this link is not problem. When I click on this link and check pin position, then I see not correct position.

I tried reached areal of "Brutal Assault festival" (for example - another places have same bug).
Link to this place on Google maps - https://www.google.cz/maps/place/Festival+Brutal+Assault/@50.3404166,15.9333541,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x470e7de678b98f57:0x775f2cf0460db4c2!8m2!3d50.3404166!4d15.9355428

### 1st try:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/50.3404166,15.9333541

this link Google transformed to:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/50%C2%B020'25.5%22N+15%C2%B056'00.1%22E/@50.3404166,15.9311654,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d50.3404166!4d15.9333541

Here is problem my coordinates are "50.3404166,15.9333541", but in final Google link I see "50.3404166,15.9311654". But I don´t know why... 1st coordinate Google allowed, but 2nd changed... Why???

### 2nd try:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=50.3404166,15.9333541
Same final link on Google, same result, same bad placed pin...

### 3nd try:

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=50.3404166,15.9333541
Same final link on Google, same result, same bad placed pin...

### 4th try:

I tried to round off coordinates, but nothing happend. When I rounded to only two decimal places then I get different place. But this is logical only "two decimal" is few.

Comment: Now I found way..
https://www.google.com/maps/place/50°20'25.6"N+15°56'07.9"E
=> Link in another format without latitude+longitude . This is way, but I prefere correct link with latitude+longitude.
Because for change format I must change all coordinates of all places in database.. :(

Comment: Why downvote without comment?
This question is not same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544268/create-google-maps-links-based-on-coordinates?rq=1 ... They need "how build link" and i need "why this link/links not work"..
=> different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latitude and longitude after the @ sign is the center of the map, not the location of the place you searched for.

The coordinates of that place are in the `data` portion of the URL:

`data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x470e7de678b98f57:0x775f2cf0460db4c2!8m2!3d50.3404166!4d15.9355428`

at the very end: `!3d50.3404166!4d15.9355428`

[link](https://www.google.cz/maps/place/50%C2%B020'25.5%22N+15%C2%B056'08.0%22E/@50.34042,15.9333541,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d50.3404166!4d15.9355428)

related:

- [How do I get the address and coordinates given this google place url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256671/how-do-i-get-the-address-and-coordinates-given-this-google-place-url)
- [Finding the lat/long coordinates in a Google Maps URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428878/finding-the-lat-long-coordinates-in-a-google-maps-url)